# Way to logout a user from the command line in OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, script, user-account

I want to logout my Mac OS X from the command line. My OS X version is 10.9.
I tried command `pkill -KILL -u uid`, but this command didn't work out.
Is there a command that can be used to log out a user from the system using command line only, not [AppleScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript)?

Comment: what exactly didn't work out?

Comment: on running the command pkill -KILL -u uid the system shows me a grey screen and on waiting for long the system shows the force quit window with no application running

Comment: Sending the `KILL` signal should be a last resort — it gives the process no opportunity to shut down cleanly, store its state, flush and close files and connections, reset hardware, or any other tidy-up, which can cause trouble in some cases.  (I usually find it best to send at least one of TERM, HUP, QUIT, ABRT, INT first, to give the process a chance to stop gracefully, and then send KILL only if all else has failed — which is rare in practice.)

Answer (score 67):

`sudo launchctl bootout gui/$(id -u <username>)`
or
`sudo launchctl bootout user/$(id -u <username>)`

Replace username with the target user's user name or replace the whole subshell with the user's uid.  This tells launchctl to teardown the users login session (gui specifically refers to the user's temporary login session, user specifies the users background processes).

You can log yourself out without the `sudo` to test this.

Note that this will ONLY work on macOS 10.11.x or newer (see `launchctl help` for more)

Comment: I JUST reread your question and I'm sorry that this won't help you, but it will come up in google search results.

Comment: Do you know opposite command to bootout? I need login user programmatically.

Comment: This is great. My Mac gets stuck after a while when I tell it to log out, and it never logs out. The second command was very persuasive.

Answer (score 30):

To log out purely from terminal (or a remote ssh session), just kill the loginwindow process:

```
sudo pkill loginwindow
```

You could get fancy and specify the user if multiple users have a loginwindow process, but this is an easy one shot, no prompt way to end a user's graphical session.

Comment: Maybe things changed since 2014, but nowadays this would log out the current user as well (there is one `loginwindow` process for each logged in user).

Answer (score 19):

This has worked for me in the past:

**Log out (with confirmation)**

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to log out'
```

**Log out directly (no confirmation)**

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to  «event aevtrlgo»'
```

or

```
osascript -e 'tell application "loginwindow" to  «event aevtrlgo»'
```

This way any running application will get noticed and can terminate in a safe fashion.

Comment: Note that « ≠ <<

Answer (score 2):

A nice utility to add to your Terminal is the "logout" command, to be used like:

```
logout UserName
```

Here the how to:

1. Edit your .bash_profile

   `nano ~/.bash_profile`
2. Add this line:

   `logout() {sudo launchctl bootout user/$(id -u "$1")}`
3. Save the file pressing `ctrl+x`
4. Restart the terminal

You are ready to go ;)

Comment: I had to break the body out onto a new line and put the closing curly brace afterwards as well.

Comment: @bmauter not for me, in the suggested form works perfectly.

Comment: Created .bash_profile and added: `logout() {sudo launchctl bootout user/$(id -u "$1")}`

I get the following error when I try to execute.

`-bash: logout: FIRSTNAME: numeric argument required`

I'm puzzled. The command works fine when used directly in the terminal, but for some reason this as a bash profile or bash script keeps spitting this error out. I wonder if it has to do with the fact that the username I am trying to test with has a space in it betwen First and Last Name? Seems like the Last name is being interpreted as an argument, yet the entry in .bash_profile has double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

It's just

```
launchctl reboot logout
```

(needs to be run under the logout-target user, so prefix with `sudo -u …a_user…`).

`man launchctl`:

> … With the logout argument given, launchd will tear down the caller's GUI login
> session in a manner *similar to a logout initiated from the Apple menu*. The key
> difference is *that a logout initiated through this subcommand will be much
> faster since it will not give apps a chance to display modal dialogs to block
> logout indefinitely*; therefore there is data corruption risk to using this
> option. *Only use it when you know you have no unsaved data in your running
> apps*. …

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple users ....

Find the Process ID with:

```
ps aux|grep login
```

Then kill that process and you logged that session out. But there are a lot of procceses left.

Check with `pstree` so you know which process to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

To get some root privileges and the # prompt, To kill all processes of another user:

```
sudo killall -vu USERNAME -HUP
```

And if it´s not all gone. Nuke em! Obligatory warning - killing things as root has no undo and no "are you sure you want to interrupt this process without saving your files, including system critical databases that might render the machine unbootable on rare occasion." type warnings.

```
sudo killall -vu USERNAME -9
```

Answer (score 1):

An extreme way to kick the user session out is to force a restart:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

This works out well if you are trying to update the system.

Comment: And you can kill the spiders in your home by burning it down, too.  Shutting down will have the *inherent* effect of kicking off users but if your goal is just to log someone out forcing a restart is on the extreme side.

Answer (score -3):

This does the trick for me

sudo -su ***user***

and for root

sudo -su root

Answer (score -5):

if you're logged with ssh to a remote computer you can logout by simply typing 'exit':

```
[host:~user]$ exit
```