# Implement feature not available in Parental Controls?

Tags: macos, parental-controls

I would like to use (or write) a timer that I can setup to use with my kids on Mac OS X (Yosemite). The functionality which I would like, which I haven't found off the shelf is:

- Set the timer for a period, T (e.g. 20 mins)
- Print a warning to the screen at T-n (e.g 17 mins)
- Lock the computer at 20 mins
- Unlock with administrator access only

I've experimented with pmset schedule but it allows the user to override.

Parental controls as currently implemented don't work for this as we want to split their time into smaller units, and more than one kid uses the same login (and I've read that this feature is buggy under Yosemite)

This timer could be started via the command line or graphically.

Comment: how would the time be set (how does it starts)?

Comment: I don't really mind. It could be via the command line, or graphically. Will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I was more thinking of "clever kids" restarting the timer :)

Comment: Right. It would need to be protected by an admin password. They haven't quite cracked that yet ;)

Comment: Without some custom script, just use the parenteral control and set it to 30 min per user.

Comment: They don't log out between sessions (they use the same account); and their sessions are shorter than 30mins.

Comment: As said, creating such complicated script might take some doing, thus using the already available is best option for now. 30 vs 20 minutes really ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm far too lazy to implement this, and I don't have kids so have no need, but it would seem imminently possible with a cute python or Terminal script set to start running at login. [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126761/way-to-logout-a-user-from-the-command-line-in-os-x-10-9) post seems to go over pretty well the Terminal logout commands. Couple that with the system time, [`date`](http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2010/01/working-with-the-date-function-in-terminal.html), is what you'll want and choose whichever output works best for you. Past that, it's somewhat unclear if you should be able to log in as a user again (just put a password on that account with no admin privileges) or if you want to have an admin log a user with no password in. The latter is probably slightly more difficult to do, but assuredly not impossible.

Comment: Those could be useful, although ideally the current user would not be logged out, just locked out.