# How can you switch users at the login screen, without administrator access, with only one local account (the administrator) and many network accounts?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, login-screen

Sometimes, a network account is logged in, and the user doesn't/forgets to log out. When someone else uses this computer, the lock screen shows. The only options that I know of from here are:

- Click cancel, which does **not** switch the user
- Force shutdown the Mac by holding down the power button
- Find their password, login, and logout

If I had an administrator, I could (probably) add another dummy local user account, and it would show a user account switcher, but I don't have admin access.

How can I switch the network account without admin access other than the above methods?

Answer (score 4):

As long as it is ok to forcibly log-out the user, you just need to to logon as the local admin using `Apple Remote Desktop` (available in the App Store) or ssh (through a terminal), and kill that user's `loginwindow` process.  You must login to the computer and not simply "Share screen" from *Finder.*  Then you will be able to login.

[Here's](http://osxdaily.com/2015/08/17/log-out-other-user-without-logging-in-mac-os-x/) a really easy-to-read article about this.

Of course, for either of those options to work, you have to enable **Remote Login** and **Remote Management** in "Sharing" under the System Preferences.  The Sharing menu is shown below:  [image: sharing menu in osx]

If you would rather use *fast-user-switching*, which I personally don't like because it can often really slow down your computer, then you can set up an "logout user after x minutes of activity" option in the System Preferences -> Security & Privacy, which will return you to a login screen.  There may also be nice hacks if you search around, that allow you to get the user-switching icon or a keyboard shortcut setup to do a fast-switch, or trigger a switch or logout by [tweaking a call to CGSession](https://superuser.com/a/46308), although that may have been possible [only in older OSX versions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126761/way-to-logout-a-user-from-the-command-line-in-os-x-10-9).  There is a huge discussion of many other ideas in that last link as well.